Чим відрізняються "себто", "цебто" і "тобто"?
Є слова "цебто", "себто" і "тобто". Вся їх відмінність у звучанні та стилі, чи може котресь з них більше підходить під певні випадки?

Вказівні займенники у нас здавна були, як би це так сказати, двох підвидів:

Цей, ця, це, ці — про те, що більш поруч. Також є варіанти сей, ся, се, сі — вони повністю еквівалентні за значенням варіантам на ц-. Саме від варіантів на с- походять варіанти на ц-, у сучасних словниках варіанти на с- позначено як застарілі.
Той, та, те, ті — про те, що більш далі.

Цебто і себто, очевидно, етимологічно пов'язані з «ближчими» вказівними займенниками. Цебто і себто повністю еквівалентні за значенням (про себто словник фактично каже, що це застарілий синонім для цебто). Тобто, очевидно, етимологічно пов'язане з «дальшими» вказівними займенниками. Про походження/значення отого -бто (яке також є в начебто), на жаль, нічого не зміг знайти.
Утім те, що цебто і себто пов'язані з «ближчими» вказівними займенниками, а тобто — з «дальшими», не означає, що вони обов'язково мають відрізнятися за значенням. «Ближчі» і «дальші» вказівні займенники доволі подібні за значенням, а різниця виявляється здебільшого при протиставленні. Коли вони стають сполучниками це і то, то їх вживають, як на мене, практично в тій самій ролі, а вибір стає лише питанням стилю:

Життя — це якась мрякувата безодня, поцяцькована подекуди й поплямована одлиском щастя та радощів (Іван Нечуй-Левицький, «Хмари», 1871).
А наука — то світло, що по дорозі життя чоловікові світить» (Микола Устиянович, «Старий Єфрем», 1849).

Висновок:

Цебто і себто повністю еквівалентні за значенням (себто вважають застарілим).
Я наразі не бачу підстав вважати, що цебто/себто і тобто відрізняються за значенням. Хоча не виключаю, що я недогледів і таку різницю може бути знайдено.

